# Segue to UINavigationController but Children UIViewControllers after rootViewController have no Navigation Bar SWIFT

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, segue

I am making a swift app and I go from a UIViewController (my login screen) to a UINavigationController with a root view (main screen post login). This all works great and all of the necessary data is passed to the root view. My issue is that after I click on a cell on the UITableViewController it takes me to the next UIViewController **but** there is no navigation bar (so I can't go back).

I also have tried unhiding the navigation bar with no success, I really think it's just not there.

I'm not sure if these are hints as to what is causing the problem but here are some warnings I get in the debugger
[Warning messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cqTY.png)

Here is the structure of my storyboard
[My storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tn3g.png)

**Here is my code to go from login to main screen**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueToTeams" {
       if let user = self.user{
            let navController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let welcomeView = navController.topViewController as! TeamsTableViewController
            welcomeView.user = user
       }
    }
}
func goToTeamsView(storyBoard : UIStoryboard){

    let welcomeView = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("teamsView")

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeView)
    super.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToTeams", sender: self)
    super.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Lastly here is my code to go from the root view controller of the UINavigationViewController (Select Team view in the storyboard screenshot) to the next one (single team view controller) which is supposed to have the navigation bar but doesn't

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("selectTeamCellSegue", sender: indexPath.row)

}
```

If you need any other info, let me know. I've been wrestling with this issue for longer than I'd like to admit, any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can embed your view controller in a navigation controller by selecting your view controller in storyboard and then select "Edit" -> "Embed in" -> "Navigation Controller". You can then add BarButtonItems to go back and forth. I guess your are using a modal segue? As far as i know, this way your view controllers are not automatically embedded in your initial navigation controller.

Hope this helps

Comment: You're completely right, that is how you would embed a view controller in a navigation controller. I think I figured out my issue though, it looks like because I was using a "Show detail" instead of a "show" segue, it was keeping the navigation bar that comes w/ the nav controller from displaying.. still a few things to work out, like why it's calling the next view twice.. but I think this issue is resolved. I appreciate your help with this, I'll accept it as the correct answer :)